# Sparse kronecker product

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a piece of code that computes the kronecker product between sparse matrices in csr format in the following way

```
import scipy.sparse as sprs
import numpy as np

A          = np.random.rand( 4,4 )
nids_left = 10
nids_right= 10  

idm      = sprs.identity( 2**(nids_left) ,dtype=A.dtype, format="csr")           
A        = sprs.kron( idm, A, format="csr" )
idm      = sprs.identity( 2**(nids_right) ,dtype=A.dtype, format="csr")           
A        = sprs.kron( A, idm, format="csr" )
```

The `nids_left` and `nids_right` indicate the total number of 2x2 identities to the left and right of the a A matrix; in other words I want to compute IxIxI...xIxAxIx...xI in an efficient way, but I just realized that `scipy.sparse` uses a single thread when doing the kronecker product. Is there a more efficient way to do this? In particular, if `nids_left` and `nids_right` become larger, memory considerations aside.

Comment: You can examine the `sparse.kron` code via the `[source]` link in the docs.  It builds the row, col, data arrays for a new COO matrix.  That's not someone else is going to do, and not suitable for multthreading or processing.  `np.kron` essentially does an `outer`, and then regroups the results into the desired 2d array.  That's a very different approach.

Comment: You don't describe or attempt to show the results, though with a 4194304x4194304 result you can't!  But it looks like you are just assembling a large sparse matrix from 4x4 blocks.  That is in both, `A` is multiplied by Identity.  That suggests you might be able to create the array from blocks directly.  In fact looking at the code I see that with dense `A`, it creates a `Block Sparse Row` format matrix - which you'd see in the result if you omitted the `csr` parameter.  Without that parameter, the first `krion` is 2x faster.